# Changing existing parameters in a relative layout

Tags: android, layout, layoutparams

I have following relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutScrollableForCentering"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addressOfProvider"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

I want to change the attribute "layout_centerHorizontal" programmatically. How can I do that?

I'm not sure which layout parameters to set:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to achieve just what I want after getting the relative layout by using:

```
RelativeLayout relLayoutForCentering = 
    (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutScrollableForCentering);
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and remove rules for RelativeLayout.LayoutParams with the [addRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int%29) and [removeRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#removeRule%28int%29) methods:

```
layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Unfortunaltey "removeRule" is not available for API level 15, which is my minimum required SDk...

Comment: @deimos1988 Yeah, I was just about to clarify that. :)

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_centerHorizontal is not the view's child's attribute but the attribute of the view itself

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

catch the layout and set the gravity of layout.

```
RelativeLayout lay=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay);
        lay.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```